# How could I set the value of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, setvalue, getattribute

I know this is not standard but I want to set the value of a div, like this:

`<div id="div" value="1">`

`document.getElementById('div').value = 2;`

to use the value you have to use `document.getElementById('div').getAttribute('value')` but I cant find any way to set it. thanks in advance!

Comment: `div`'s don't have a value attribute. You can use a [data- attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to store a value which can then be  retrieved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set a value to a div. Instead you can try to add a data attribute, like this:

`<div id="div" data-value="1">`

And if you want to access the data-value from javascript, just use

`elem.dataset.{data_attribute_name};`, in this case: `document.getElementById('div').dataset.value;`

Note that you can set multiple data attributes to one element, making it much more versatile than using value.